# Is there a way to logon on to a new SAPsystem out of ABAP coding?

Tags: authentication, abap, function-module

To work and code within a SAP System you first have to log yourself into a certain system with a user.

Is there a way that I can trigger this logon process to a new SAP System within ABAP?

For example:

```
CALL FUNCTION "LOGON_TO_OTHER_SAP_SYSTEM"
EXPORTING 
 iv_system_id = "123"
 iv_url = "https://www.someSAPsystemDestinationUrl"
```

And then the all-known logon window pops up and you're able to log yourself in?
The initial SAP System connection closes or has to be closed?

I hope you get what I mean! :)

Thanks

Comment: I guess you are talking about the feature that is provided in transaction code `SM59` to log in to any system defined as a RFC destination. It calls the following function module via RFC (`CALL FUNCTION 'SYSTEM_REMOTE_LOGIN' DESTINATION 'here your RFC destination'.`) Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: You need to clarify what do you want to do after logon. Do you want to open a SAP GUI session on the remote system? Or do you want to execute some function and get the result?

Comment: The Firefighter feature from SAP GRC does pretty much that, so there should be a way to accomplish this. Although it skips the login window. It just opens a new window where you are already logged into the other system as the new user.

Comment: What Sandra suggested. SYSTEM_REMOTE_LOGIN. Assuming you are in the SAPGui,  I would add that if you set up a trusted relationship between the 2 systems, in SM59 the logon screen isnt necessary. https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAPConn/Create+an+RFC+trust+relationship+between+2+SAP+systems+-+A+step-by-step+guide